# Correctly using Component and Children Component with accessing parents state

Tags: reactjs

We are having comments and each comment has childrens (answers, also comments)
We initialize the component like this:

```
=react_component "CommentList", url: object_comments_path(current_object), page: 1
```

We have the following Reactcomponents

CommentList
Comment
VoteBar
EditBar

they are used in the following order (the list then renders many comments, each comment renders a votebar and an editbar)

```
CommentList
-> Comment
  -> VoteBar
  -> EditBar
```

If the CommentList is initialized, it loads the comments (page 1) from the server and save them into a state.

```
this.setState( {comments: all_comments} );
```

the render function then simply renders the list of comments

```
# CommentList
render: function() {
  comments = this.state.comments.map(function(comment) {
    return <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} />
  });
  return <div className="commentsList">{comments}</div>
}
```

**my questions: **

we give each `Comment` its values as a property. If we want to `vote` a comment, (which the VoteBar is doing), how then can we change the state of `CommentList`, so that the comment there is flagged as `voted=true`?

is there a better way of doing this? can we bi-directional put states into other classes? lets say the commentlist gives `&comment` into the `Comment`. If we change the state of `Comment`, the `CommentList` will automatically have the state also changed, and if we change the List, the Comment will have it also (because it renders again, right?)

** is this the general way of thinking how React is working, or is this way off?**

Comment: Use redux or similar. When `vote up` button is pressed, trigger a action which dispatches redux action to make appropriate changes in state of CommentList. When CommentList changes, it will re-render, and changes will be reflected in child components too.

Comment: never heared, will have a look into it now

Comment: gosh, checked it for 1 hour - understand pretty much nothing. all these tutorials and things are (as usual) far away from realtity and never display common usecases, leaving a developer, who needs a quick insight super frustrated :(

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar no, i found a react way :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created simple example for you. Can't put all code here so download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8JlN3K_3e8KZGdka1M4TG8yUHM/view?usp=sharing)

Steps to run

```
1. Extract and change directory
2. npm install
3. npm start
```

It should start you browser or go to **localhost:3000**

Comments in the code explains much of the stuff

Hope it helps